# How can I create a SYSTEMTIME struct from ULONGLONG milliseconds?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, datetime

Rather than using WMI to obtain the last boot time, I wanted to calculate it using `::GetSystemTime()` and `::GetTickCount64`. But once I get to milliseconds, I don't know how to get back to a FILETIME object.

I tried this:

```c
static ULONGLONG FileTimeToMillis(const FILETIME &ft)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
    uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime; // could use memcpy here!
    uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

    return uli.QuadPart/10000;
}

static void MillisToSystemTime(ULONGLONG millis, SYSTEMTIME *st)
{
   UINT64 t = static_cast<UINT64>(-10000) * static_cast<UINT64>(millis);

   FILETIME ft;
   ft.dwLowDateTime = static_cast<DWORD(t & 0xFFFFFFFF);
   ft.dwHighDateTime = static_cast<DWORD>(t >> 32);

   ::FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, st);
}

void main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st, lt, st2, lt2;

    ::GetSystemTime(&st);
    ::GetLocalTime(&lt);

    cout << "The system time is: " << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute << ":" << st.wSecond << endl;
    cout << "The local time is: "  << lt.wHour << ":" << lt.wMinute << ":" << lt.wSecond << endl;

    FILETIME sft, lft;
    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &sft);
    ::SystemTimeToFileTime(&lt, &lft);  

    cout << "The system time in millis is: " << FileTimeToMillis(sft) << endl;
    cout << "The local time in millis is: "  << FileTimeToMillis(lft) << endl;

    MillisToSystemTime(FileTimeToMillis(sft), &st2);
    MillisToSystemTime(FileTimeToMillis(sft), &lt2);

    cout << "The system time (post conversion) is: " << st2.wHour << ":" << st2.wMinute << ":" << st2.wSecond << endl;
    cout << "The local time (post conversion) is: "  << lt2.wHour << ":" << lt2.wMinute << ":" << lt2.wSecond << endl;
}
```

But I certainly don't get what's expected. Instead, I get:

```
The system time is: 15:5:2
The local time is: 10:5:2
The system time in millis is: 12984678302935
The local time in millis is: 12984660302935
The system time (post conversion) is: 52428:52428:52428
The local time (post conversion) is: 52428:52428:52428
```

Any ideas? Please don't tell me to use Boost or  because it's not available to me.

Comment: In pseudo code you want `FileTimeToSystemTime(GetSystemTimeAsFileTime - (10000 * GetTickCount64))`

Comment: @arx MSDN recommends against performing arithmetic on the FILETIME structure itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The system time (post conversion) is: 52428:52428:52428

When you get weirdo values, always convert to hex first.   52428 == 0xcccc.  That's the value that the debug build generated code uses to initialize variables.  So you are looking at uninitialized memory.

Next defense strategy is to *never* ignore the return value of Windows api function.  Use a VERIFY() macro, like the one available in MFC.  You'll then easily see that FileTimeToSystemTime() fails.

The bug is -10000.

Comment: D'Oh! Sticking a negative number into an unsigned is a rookie error!! I was using code I found via Google and they were using __int64, I didn't change the -10000 to 10000. Good catch!!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was doing the arithmetic incorrectly. Once I read up on `ULARGE_INTEGER` and `FILETIME`, I figured out that I could directly work with the `QuadPart` of the `ULARGE_INTEGER` and then pull out the high and low pieces correctly, while avoiding bit shifting and casting confusion.

```cpp
static UINT64 FileTimeToMillis(const FILETIME &ft)
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
    uli.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime; // could use memcpy here!
    uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;

    return static_cast<UINT64>(uli.QuadPart/10000);
}

static void MillisToSystemTime(UINT64 millis, SYSTEMTIME *st)
{
    UINT64 multiplier = 10000;
    UINT64 t = multiplier * millis;

    ULARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.QuadPart = t;
    // NOTE, DON'T have to do this any longer because we're putting
    // in the 64bit UINT directly
    //li.LowPart = static_cast<DWORD>(t & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    //li.HighPart = static_cast<DWORD>(t >> 32);

    FILETIME ft;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = li.LowPart;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = li.HighPart;

    ::FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, st);
}
```

Key was reading the following from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the
>   FILETIME structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should copy
>   the low- and high-order parts of the file time to a ULARGE_INTEGER
>   structure, perform 64-bit arithmetic on the QuadPart member, and copy
>   the LowPart and HighPart members into the FILETIME structure.